# Android treemap visual for a dir?

Tags: android, treemap

Is there a GUI item to visualize a dir structure (treemap) 
in android?

Thanks, Leslie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) is the closest component you can find on Android platform for a tree structure but it will only show one level of depth.

I suggest you read [this thread on google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/d84a6b360fbf035e) to understand why it doesn't really exist in android. Basically, it would not be easy to use on a touch interface.

I can also suggest you to use a ExpandableListView with, at its top, some kind of breadcrumb to display the path of the actual node exposed by the ExpandableListView.

Regards, Stéphane